# Component in nested route renders itself instead in this.props.children

Tags: react-router

I am trying to display a form, nested inside a parent view using the following route configuration:

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Landing}/>
      <Route path='applications' component={Applications}>
        <Route path='/new' component={ApplicationForm}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

When visiting `/applications`, I render my `Applications` component

```
class Applications extends Component {
  renderContent () {
    return (
      <div className="dashboard">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <DashboardLayout
        content={this.renderContent()}
        {...this.props}/>
    );
  };
}
```

But for some reason, the `Applications` component also gets rendered into `this.props.children`, but without the props of the initial render